# Trying to emulate 'new' operator

Tags: javascript, constructor

How can I emulate 'new' operator with function myNew? Tried everything but I can't get it work.

```js
function Person(name) {
 this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
 return this.name;
}

function myNew(){
  var obj = Object.create(Object.prototype);
  var instance = this.apply(obj, arguments);
  return instance;
}


var person = myNew(Person, 'Test');
console.log(person instanceof Person);  // true
person.getName();   // Test
```

Comment: Your `myNew` function does not take `Person` as an argument. Did you mean to pass it for the context, as in `myNew.call(Person, 'Test')`?

Comment: Obviously the new object should not inherit from `Object.prototype` but the one you've chosen.

Comment: Just use `Reflect.construct` :-)

Comment: Once I did it. I don't remember exactly now, but I could try to

Comment: Try doing ```function myNew(constructor) {...}``` and use ```constructor``` instead of ```this```. Then convert arguments to array and shift it. I will post an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you want an emulation without Reflect.construct, try this:

```
function myNew(constructor) {
  var instance = Object.create(constructor.prototype)
  var args = Array.from(arguments)
  args.shift()
  constructor.apply(instance, args)
  return instance
}
```

If you support ES6, you can write it shorter as:

```
function myNew(constructor, ...args) {
  var instance = Object.create(constructor.prototype)
  constructor.apply(instance, args)
  return instance
}
```

Edit: Just noticed Array.from is available in ES6 but if you want to support ES5, you can easily simulate it

Edit 2:
Looking to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) page of the new operator, I noticed that I forgot an important step in object creation from a constructor. The algorithm I used is almost identical to the one explained on the page except for the crucial part that, **there are constructors that actually return something** (not all constructors return `undefined`). In this case, the returned **object** *is* the evaluation of the new expression. So the final form (I hope) of the function will be

```
function myNew(constructor, ...args) {
  var instance = Object.create(constructor.prototype)
  var obj = constructor.apply(instance, args)
  if(obj instanceof Object) return obj
  return instance
}
```

Comment: Tried your answer, but it didn't work:(
Throws TypeError: person is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reflect.construct`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct

```js
function Person(name) {
 this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
 return this.name;
}


var person = Reflect.construct(Person, ['Test']);
console.log(person instanceof Person);  // true
console.log(person.getName());   // Test
```